# Winding number of a composition.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My topology professor gave us this exercise to think about (it isn't homework, but it's obvious enough to him that he didn't feel the need to prove it to us):
Given two continuous maps $f,g: [0,1] \to S^1$ find a formula that relates deg($f$) and deg($g$) to deg($f\circ g$).

My intuition tells me that we should get deg($f$)deg($g$) = deg($f\circ g$).
On the road to supplying a proof, I thought to consider $F$ and $G$, which are lifts of f and g, respectively, then prove that $F\circ G$ is a lift of $f\circ g$. This seemed like the best way to be able to use the fact that $f$ and $g$ have a given degree.
Even in that case, $(F\circ G)(1) - (F\circ G)(0) = F(G(1)) - F(G(0))$, but I'm not quite sure what to do with that information.

I would appreciate some help proving my formula, or for someone to tell me it is incorrect.
Some nuances about the way this was explained to me: we have been saying that a function $\tilde{f}$ is a lift of $f$ if $e\circ \tilde{f} = f$, where $e:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ is given by $e(x) = (\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x)$. The degree of a function $f$ from $S^1$ to itself was defined to be the unique integer $\tilde{f}(1)-\tilde{f}(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Any map $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is homotopic to a map $h_n : S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^n$ (considering $S^1 \subseteq \Bbb C$), for some $n\in\Bbb Z$, and this $n$ is unique and is the degree of $f$. So assume $f \simeq h_n$ and $g \simeq h_m$, then 
$$f \circ g \simeq h_n \circ h_m = h_{nm}$$
So your intuition is correct: $\text{deg}(f\circ g)=\text{deg}(f)\text{deg}(g)$.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is find $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $e \circ F = f \circ e$. Then $F$ restricted to $[0,1]$ is a usual lift of $f$, and $F$ satisfies the nice property that $F(m) - F(n) = (m - n)(F(1) - F(0))$ for any integers $m$ and $n$ (since it's just a usual lift of $f$ repeated over and over).

Then if $G$ is a lift of $g$, $(F \circ G)(1) - (F \circ G)(0) = F(G(1)) - F(G(0)) = (G(1) - G(0))(F(1) - F(0))$.

Also there's a small domain issue in trying to form $f \circ g$ but I guess not a huge problem if $f(0) = f(1)$.